# Spark how to optimize RE-encoding of key-value pairs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My problem is to encode key-value pairs such that all the values are continuous integers starting from 0.

Data **before** RE-encoding:

> 10 -> 11
>
> 15 -> 12
>
> 13 -> 10
>
> 18 -> 20
>
> 10 -> 15
>
> 15 -> 11

Data **after** RE-encoding:

> 10 -> 0
>
> 15 -> 1
>
> 13 -> 2
>
> 18 -> 3
>
> 10 -> 4
>
> 15 -> 0

Here is how I implement this:

```
val encoding = data.map(_.swap).groupByKey().zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._1._1, x._2))
val data_new = data.map(_.swap).join(encoding).map(x => (x._2._1, x._2._2.toInt))
```

But my implementation is very **slow**, and I am wondering is there **any better method** to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: why is `15 -> 0` expected in that sequence? Looks like `zipWithIndex` would solve that without the need for join, no?

Comment: @maasg As long as the encoding is continuous, it will work for me. In this specific example, because the value 11 is mapped to 0, so that 15->11 should be 15->0.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is following,

Assuming `data` is a `RDD[ ( Int, Int ) ]` of `key-value` tuples.

```
val newData = data
  .groupBy( { case ( key, value ) => value } )
  .zipWithIndex
  .sortBy( { case ( ( value, iter ), index ) => index } )
  .flatMap( { case ( ( value, iter ), index ) => {
    iter.map( { case ( key, value ) => ( key, index ) } ) 
  } } )
```